# For example, in the sched_ext example execution, or in the context of ebpf, what can be done to output information to log files

Tags: c, linux

For example, in the 'SCHED_EXT' example execution, or in the context of 'EBPF', what can be done to output information to log files is not acceptables

```
s32 BPF_STRUCT_OPS(simple_select, struct task_struct \*p,s32 prev_cpu, u64 wake_flags) 
{
  bpf_trace_printk(KERN_INFO "Task %s\[%d\] selected CPU %d\\n",p-\>comm, p-\>pid, 2);
  return 2;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Even your title makes no sense.

Comment: Hi, welcome on StackOverflow. In order to achieve your chances of getting a good answer, please edit your question. What is the context of your problem? I.e. what are you trying to achieve overall? What is your specific problem? What have you tried so far to solve your problem?
Also, have you included all the code that is necessary to understand your problem and to come up with a solution?